# Analytics Goal Funnel Regex doesn't recognize "example.html?p=2"

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I have my goal funnel set up and this is the regex for one of the stages: `^/shop/(.*)`

This will match pages such as `/shop/collections/art.html` but when I look at the goal funnel, it says people are dropping out by going to pages like `/shop/collections/art.html?p=2`. Notice the `?p=2` is the only difference here.

I tried to do it as `^/shop/((.|\?)*)` but I'm not sure that's fixing it.

How do I fix this?